# django set image delete old reference and prevent delete default

Tags: python, django, django-models, imagefield

despite of many mordern website employ an OSS for serving image, I still want to build a backend to manage small thumbnails locally.

however, django image field is a bit tricky.

there are three views I may change image reference:

- `models.py`
- `views.py`
- `forms.py`

I used to do it simply by:

`forms.py`

```py
request.user.profile.image = self.files['image']
```

and I always have a default

`models.py`

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = ProcessedImageField(
        default='profile/default.jpg', 
        upload_to='profile', 
        processors=[ResizeToFill(*THUMBNAIL_SIZE)],
        format='JPEG',
        options={'quality': THUMBNAIL_QUALITY}, 
    )
```

After a lot of testing, I found that it always result in an issue, can be among:

- default image file get deleted.
- if the image has been set before, it holds an value that is not the default, when I reset it, the old referenced file is not deleted and will occupy disk storage.

to do it perfectly, I decided to write a global function for import, **whenever I want to set an image, call it**

```py
from django.conf import settings

def setImage(instance, attr, file):
    """ instance will be saved """
    if file:
        ifield = getattr(instance, attr)
        # old reference, can be default
        iurl = ifield.url
        # default
        durl = settings.MEDIA_URL + instance._meta.get_field(attr).get_default()
        if iurl != durl:
            # old reference is not default
            # delete old reference and free up space
            ifield.delete(save=True)
        # set new file 
        setattr(ifield, attr, file)
    instance.save()
```

pretty straight-forward. however, in testing, I found the image will never be set. Following are the possibale reasons I have eliminated:

- form `multipart` `enctype` attribute
- ajax `processData`, `contentType` is correctly set
- `save` in model class is not overriden

if it's all ok, where went wrong? I logged out all the values.

```py
setImage(self.user.profile, 'image', self.files['image'])
# self.files['image'] has valid value and is passed 
# to setImage, which I think, is not garbage collected
```

```py
def setImage(instance, attr, file):
    """ instance will be saved """
    print('======')
    print(file)
    if file:
        ifield = getattr(instance, attr)
        iurl = ifield.url
        durl = settings.MEDIA_URL + instance._meta.get_field(attr).get_default()
        print(iurl)
        print(durl)
        if iurl != durl:
            ifield.delete(save=True)
            print(f'--- del {iurl}')
        setattr(ifield, attr, file)
        print('----res')
        print(getattr(ifield, attr))
        print(ifield.image)
    print('--- ins')
    print(instance)
    instance.save()
    print('--- after save')
    print(instance.image.url)
    print(getattr(instance, attr))
```

the field has a default value, and I upload the screen shot in testing.

```
======
Screen Shot 2022-11-03 at 10.59.41 pm.png
/media/profile/default.jpg
/media/profile/default.jpg
----res
Screen Shot 2022-11-03 at 10.59.41 pm.png
Screen Shot 2022-11-03 at 10.59.41 pm.png
--- ins
tracey
--- after save
/media/profile/default.jpg
profile/default.jpg
```

---

why the image is not setting, anybody have any ideas?

---

### Solutions

after tons of testing, only a line went wrong and just simple a wrong variable.

```py
def setImage(instance, attr, file):
    """ instance will be saved """
    if file:
        ifield = getattr(instance, attr)
        iurl = ifield.url
        durl = settings.MEDIA_URL + instance._meta.get_field(attr).get_default()
        if iurl != durl:
            ifield.delete(save=True)
        setattr(instance, attr, file)
        instance.save()
```

---

for form update validation, here's a method I've worked out and testified working:

```py
def clean_image(form, attr:str, field:str):
    """ 
    form.instance.attr -> ImageFile
    form.cleaned_data[field] -> ImageFile
    """
    upload_img = form.cleaned_data[field]
    if form.instance:
        # condition: update
        # create does not matter 
        ifield = getattr(form.instance, attr)
        iurl = ifield.url
        if isinstance(upload_img, InMemoryUploadedFile):
            # upload new file
            # else, the file is not changed
            durl = settings.MEDIA_URL + form.instance._meta.get_field(attr).get_default()
            if iurl != durl:
                ifield.delete(save=True)
    return upload_img
```

e.g. you can call it simply like:

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    image = ProcessedImageField(
        default='projects/default.jpg', 
        upload_to='projects', 
        processors=[ResizeToFill(*THUMBNAIL_SIZE)],
        options={'quality': THUMBNAIL_QUALITY}, 
        format='JPEG',
    )

class ProjectCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name', 'image']
    
    def clean_image(self):
        return clean_image(self, 'image', 'image')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I did not test your function to say what is wrong with it. Instead I implemented it in my own way taking your model as a base. If you really want a `set_image(instance, attr, file)` function, you can adapt it from this answer `create_profile_ajax` at views.py.

settings.py

```
DEFAULT_IMAGE_URL = 'profile/default.jpg'
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = ProcessedImageField(
        default=settings.DEFAULT_IMAGE_URL,
        upload_to='avatars',
        processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 50)],
        format='JPEG',
        options={'quality': 60},
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    @staticmethod
    def default_image_absolute_url():
        return settings.MEDIA_URL + settings.DEFAULT_IMAGE_URL
    
    @staticmethod
    def default_image_url():
        return settings.DEFAULT_IMAGE_URL
```

forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def create_profile(request):
    form = ProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'profile/create.html', {'form': form})


def create_profile_ajax(request):
    image = request.FILES.get('image')
    profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)

    if image:
        if profile.image.url == Profile.default_image_absolute_url():
            profile.image = image
        else:
            profile.image.delete()
            profile.image = image
    else:
        profile.image = Profile.default_image_url()
    
    profile.save()
    profile.refresh_from_db()

    return JsonResponse({'new_image_url': profile.image.url})
```

profile/create.html ([csrf with ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax))

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{{form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" value="Create" onclick="sendProfile()">

<img src="{{request.user.profile.image.url}}" 
    id="thumb" 
    width="500" 
    height="600" 
    {% if not request.user.profile.image %} hidden {% endif %} 
    style="object-fit: contain;">


<script>
    function getCookie(name) {
        ...
    }

    function sendProfile() {
        const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        var input = document.getElementById('id_image');
        var data = new FormData()
        data.append('image', input.files[0])

        fetch('/your/ajax/url/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
        },
        body: data
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            var thumb = document.getElementById('thumb');
            thumb.src = data.new_image_url;
            thumb.hidden = false;
            input.value = '';
        });
    }
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

quotting [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) documentation:

> When using FormData to submit POST requests using XMLHttpRequest or
> the Fetch_API with the multipart/form-data Content-Type (e.g. when
> uploading Files and Blobs to the server), do not explicitly set the
> Content-Type header on the request.